# Is LightHouse Performance Testing tool Compatible with Electron 1.8.1

Tags: google-chrome, performance-monitor, performance-tuning

I'm trying to do a robust performance test on our Angular Electron app. I heard LightHouse is excellent on Chrome but when I try to use it on Electron it fails with:
Browser.getVersion() not found

Is there a way to make LightHouse compatible with Electron?

If not, what performance tools (other than CDT) Can I use?

thanks